# nginx proxypass for video/audio from amazon cloud drive

Tags: nginx, proxypass, video, audio, html5

I have a mp3 file on my amazon cloud drive:

How can I make nginx proxy_pass to play this audio on chrome?

I need to get content range header, then send the content-range header to proxy server.

Configuration:

```
location /match/here.mp3 {
    proxy_pass https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/templink/uIBwvxaYbNEQFB8gUjIgu6h9RjLdu18nKGxterGfh9MFfJttb;
}
```

And the link is: http://46.101.231.60/match/here.mp3

Simple when I enter this link (http://46.101.231.60/match/here.mp3) on chrome the audio is not playing. How can I fix it?

Comment: You might need to forcibly set the correct mime type so your browser can recognise the content as audio

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location /match/here.mp3 {
    try_files @amazon;
}

location @amazon{
#resolver important to resolve the host,google dns
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/templink/uIBwvxaYbNEQFB8gUjIgu6h9RjLdu18nKGxterGfh9MFfJttb;
}
```

Also check the error log on nginx , maybe that can help

Comment: not worked. with your code I cannot reload or restart nginx